# How to control element from a different page while using routing in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am taking an example of a simple login form.
Below is some of the content from index.html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-static-top">
        <li><a href="#!signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log In</a></li>

        <li><a href="#!login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log out</a></li>

    </ul>
```

These are the controllers I have used:

```
var app = angular
.module('ModuleApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: 'home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
        .when("/signup", {
            templateUrl: 'signup.html',
            controller: 'signupController'
        })
        .when("/login", {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        })
        .when("/database", {
            templateUrl: 'database.html',
            controller: 'databaseController'
        })
       ;
})
```

My aim is to create a login page. After user logs in I want to hide the anchor elements "Sign up" and "Log In" and it will show 'log out' anchor element.
So it will be controlled by the submit button in the login page i.e. 'login.html'.

How to control the elements of index.html from a different page? How to hide and disable this 'login' button after logging in i.e. with a click of submit button?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a global state that will check if the user is already logged.

I don't recommend that because of security issue, but you can do this:

```
    <li ng-if="!logged"><a href="#!signup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
    <li ng-if="!logged"><a href="#!login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log In</a></li>
    <li ng-if="logged"><a href="#!login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log out</a></li>
```

In your controller logic, when user authentication is done, change your `logged` value.

```
$rootScope.logged = true;
```